# Square root of number python

Tags: python, square-root, math.sqrt

Here's my code:

```
import cmath
root = (cmath.sqrt(25))
print (root)
raw_input()
```

The problem i face is the result of root is 5+0j which is undesirable i only want the square root. How can i fix this?

Comment: `cmath` is good if you want to know `sqrt(-25)` :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `math` module instead of the `cmath` module; the latter is for complex numbers only:

```
>>> import math
>>> print math.sqrt(25)
5.0
```

For what it's worth, the `cmath` result is correct, *if you expected a complex number*. You could take just the `.real` component of the result, but since there is a regular floating point equivalent in the `math` module there is no point in having your computer do the extra work.

Answer (score 3):

The result itself is correct. The square root of `25 + 0j` is `5 + 0j`.

Where did the `j` come from ? Its implicit because you are using the complex math (`cmath`) library.

If you only want the *real* part of the complex number, then do :

```
>>> root = (cmath.sqrt(25))
>>> root.real
5.0
```

Lastly, if you want to deal with only real numbers, then use the `math` library.

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct!

That's because you're using the complex math library to find the square root.

After all,

```
5+0j
```

Is the complex square root of 25:

```
(5+0j)*(5+0j) = 25 + 2*0j + (0j)^2 = 25 + 0 + 0 = 25
```

Use the `math` module instead for "regular" square roots.

Or: use access the real part via:

```
root.real
```

Generally, you may want to use complex numbers instead of natural numbers for generality and for math error detection - but that's another discussion.

Answer (score 0):

`cmath` is good for complex numbers, not real ones. This should work!

```
import math
import cmath
def sqrt(n):
    if n < 0:
        return cmath.sqrt(n)
    else:
        return math.sqrt(n)
```